# How to use cookies with Azure AD on behalf of flow to get an access token to another resource

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, openid, azure-active-directory

I have two applications using the same azure active directory. App A and App B.

App A uses

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {

            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
            Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"],
            CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"],                      
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken, 
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",
            SaveTokens = true,                                                              
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
            }        

        });
```

And i acquire an access to application B api service resource by acquiring the token with:

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
    {         
        string userObjectId = (context.Ticket.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"], Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"]);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"]);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
            context.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(context.Properties.Items[OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey]), clientCred, Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:GraphResourceId"]);
```

I'm also using cookies to sign in into app A with:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnSignedIn = OnSignedIn,
                OnSigningIn = OnSigningIn,
                OnValidatePrincipal = OnValidatePrincipal                    
            }
        });
/* Account Controller SignIn() */
return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IsPersistent = true,                                      
                RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Now my problem is similar to others where my access token is expiring, but my signin cookie to app a is still valid so the user appears to be logged in fine, although they have no token in the cache.

I've followed suit of other questions and looked to my Cookie event of

```
 Task OnValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext arg) {

     var http = new HttpClient();
                var uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token";
                var client_id = "<my_client_id>";
                var scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read";
                var refresh_token = "<saved_refresh_token_in_cookie_if_SaveTokens = true>";
                var redirect_uri = "https://localhost:20352/";
                var grant_type = "refresh_token";
                var client_secret = "<client_secret_from_azure>";
                var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", client_id),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", scope),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", refresh_token),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirect_uri),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", grant_type),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", client_secret)
                        };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

                var result = http.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
                var stringContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(stringContent);
                var token = jobject["access_token"].Value<string>();
```

Problem here is I don't know how to get this token back into the default TokenStore that the adal AuthenticationContext uses. We have code deeper that needs to pull from:

```
_authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_authConfigOptions.AzureAd.WebserviceAppIdUri.ToString(), credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

Is there a way I can get a new resource access token back into the tokenstore for users App B api calls, without a valid token / refresh token 'On Behalf of User' flow?

Comment: Without an access token or refresh token, no. You have to send them to authenticate in Azure AD. But shouldn't you have a refresh token in cache? Those last 14 days (IIRC) so it's not necessary to do the redirect.

Comment: Well im trying to handle the scenario where app A cookie does authenticate, but for whatever reason access / refresh token for resource B is invalid or purged. So redirect to reauthorize is pulling from the cookie and allowing a passthrough signing them into app A, without an access token. I need to purge the cookie then, and redirect to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you lose the access token and refresh token, you must redirect the user to Azure AD to authenticate again. They may be still authenticated there so they just get redirected back to your app along with the authorization code.

In one of my projects I made an exception filter that does this:

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    //If the error is a silent token acquisition exception from ADAL..
    if(filterContext.Exception is AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException)
    {
        //Instead of the usual procedure, return a 401 which triggers the OpenIdConnect middleware redirection
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

So if the exception is thrown where silent token acquisition fails, just swallow the error and change the result into a 401, which triggers the OpenIdConnect middleware to send the user to Azure AD.

Since you have `AutomaticAuthenticate=true`, it should do this.

Comment: HttpUnauthorizedResult should be UnauthorizedResult for ASP.NET Core MVC.